# Tool for automated UI testing for Mac OS X (Cocoa) apps

Tags: cocoa, macos, ui-automation

Is there any open-source free tool for automated UI testing for Mac OS X (Cocoa) apps?
So far I've seen commercial tools such as [Squish] and [EggPlant]. The only free tools I've read about are using [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009771-CH1-SW1) or [Automator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Automator.html).
Does anyone have any experience with these tools? any other options I should consider?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at http://sikuli.org/ - that lets you automize your OS X GUI tests (for free).

Comment: It is not supporting in 10.10.

Answer (score 6):

I created an open source Python package that uses the Apple Accessibility API among others to create a classic GUI automation library, giving you visibility into and interaction with Cocoa GUIs. [PyATOM home page](http://pyatom.com/) and [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom)

Answer (score 3):

AppleScript is another option for simple ui simulation.

(no, you do not need to create a scripting definition to perform basic tasks)

Comment: What do you mean by scripting definition? That I don't need to write the script itself and use recording?

Comment: that you don't need to teach your app to respond to custom commands - some are free

Comment: Can you elaborate? I see that for existing apps I have "Dictionaries" I can use in my scripts... What about simple actions like pressing a button, etc... without recording through Automator?

Comment: yes, you can do that via the commands in System Events. simulate keystrokes, mouse movement, choosing menu items, view crawling and selecting a button all with applescript (assuming you've written a cocoa app)